# Python problem with importing from couple directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests

I have problem with importing modules to my automation tests.
What exactly I'm talking about?
Here is my file structure:

```
PROJECT/
    package1/
        server_one.py
        config/
            logging_system/
                logging_config.py
        subpackage/
            something.py
    package2/
        server_two.py
        config/
            logging_system/
                logging_config.py
        sobpackage/
            something.py
    tests/
        test_one.py
        text_two.py
        etc.
```

And now, when I try to import my servers so I type:
from package1.server_one as ServerOne
from package2.server_two as ServerTwo

I got error
File "\package\server_one.py", line 5, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'

Everything working when I run it manually:
python3 .\package1\server_one.py
and in second console:
python3 .\package2\server_two.py

How I can resolve it? Every suggestion will be welcome.

P.S
Packages names are random, I can't copy-paste full work structure because It's too many files/directories there.

I try to use sys.path to resolve this problem.

In 'tests' directory I write something like this:

```
current_path = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1]
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}")
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}/package1")


from package1.server_one import ServerOne
```

and then it's work but only for package1
when I add following lines:

```
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}/package2")
from package2.server_two import ServerTwo
```

so full import look like this:

```
current_path = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1]
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}")
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}/package1")
sys.path.append(f"{current_path}/package2")

from package1.server_one import ServerOne
from package2.server_two import ServerTwo
```

Then I got error:

```
 File "<PATH>\package2\server_two.py", line 5, in <module>
    from config.logging_system.logging_config import Logger
ImportError: cannot import name 'Logger' from 'config.logging_system.logging_config' 
(<PATH>/package1\config\logging_system\logging_config.py)
```

What's weird in this error is that, error occur in line 5 in server_two.py but full path shows that it try to import not from his own directory.

The structure should look like this because package1 and package2 are 2 separate backend servers and they have to run at the same time on different devices (they speak between them)
So tests have to prepare both this server and then test communication

How can I resolve this problem? package1 and package2 should use only them own .py files and configs and should can be run from tests files as subprocess (only for tests)
I can't separates tests for package1 in directory with package1 and tests for package2 in directory with package2.

Comment: `from package1.server_one as ServerOne` is not valid Python. Please post code that actually produces the observed errors.

Comment: You also have two directories on your path that provide a top-level module named `config`. It appears that you are always using the one defined in `package1`, even when you intend to use the one defined in `package2`. You probably want to look at using relative imports instead of putting so many directories on `sys.path`.

Comment: @chepner sorry my bad. I corrected it.

Comment: @chepner So should I changes names of directories? because when I run it manually (both servers) they use separates configs. 
To use relative imports you mean? When I remove sys.path.append() i got ValueError: Empty module name

Comment: You need to actually package your project then install it with pip. Stop messing with `sys.path`, this is virtually never the correct way to do things. Then, you should use fully qualified imports, e.g. `from package1.config.logging_system.logging_config import Logger` or whatever (although, you *could* use relative imports, but the point is, you need to package and install your project)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't want to use sys.path. I try it because only this solution I found but in my case it also not work. What do you mean by package my project? There is no possibility to do it like that in 'develop' enviroment?

Comment: yes, you can `pip install -e` to install it in editable mode, although, you shouldn't do that during tests. The testing environment should install the package it is testing and the tests should be written with the assumption that the package is installed normally.

Comment: And this is what I mean by packaging: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Note, you don't have to build the distribution files or upload the distribution files to PyPi. Just the stuff before that

Comment: Ok but what's the point of package my project? It shouldn't work with the structure like now? When I move tests into package1 then I can test this package1 without any problems but problem is when I have to test both packages at the same time.